# Delegates and thread: CallbackContext parameter

Tags: c++, multithreading, delegates, windows-runtime, workitem

I'm implementing threading in Metro mode, I got this example while Googling, but I don't understand `CallbackContext` . What's the use of this? [This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh755798%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) explains its use in MTA, but not clear to me. And I'm facing problem when I use `CallbackContext` as `Any` or `Same`. Something work with one but not with other! So first thing first I want to know what's the use of this?! PS: I'm new to WindowsRT programming and C++ too! Thanks!

```
auto workItemHandler = ref new WorkItemHandler([=](IAsyncAction^)
{
    // Run the user callback.
    try
    {
        func(data);
    }
    catch (...)
    { 

    }
    // Signal that the thread has completed.
    SetEvent(completionEvent);
    //CloseHandle(completionEvent);

}, CallbackContext::Same);
```

Answer (score 2):

`CallbackContext` determines whether your delegate (in this case, a `WorkItemHandler`) aggregates the free-threaded marshaller.  This will determine whether your delegate can be smuggled to another apartment (`CallbackContext::Any`), or if it must be called back to the originating apartment (`CallbackContext::Same`).  Basically, it tells the person invoking your delegate whether it can be called directly regardless of apartment, or if they need to marshal back to the apartment it was created in.

For example, in a Windows Store Application, anything that modifies the UI needs to run on the UI thread (STA).  Let's presume the method you're in is one that runs on the UI thread (such as an event callback, like a button click handler).  Certain async calls like `ThreadPool::RunAsync` will run the passed-in delegate on a thread *other* than the UI thread (as the default for delegates is `CallbackContext::Any`).  This is useful if you do not need to do anything on the UI thread, as it frees that thread up to continue pumping messages (and your app continues to feel performant).

However, if you do need to modify the UI or make a call back into the UI, and you attempt to do so from a non-UI thread, you will get an incorrect thread exception.  By adding the parameter `CallbackContext::Same` you can force your delegate to run in the originating apartment (in this scenario, the STA) and thereby avoid the issue.

(You can also make a call back to the UI thread by using `Dispatcher->RunAsync` to invoke a further delegate to run on the STA.  Whether it's better for your entire delegate to run on the STA or not depends on your scenario.)